# retrieve edit values in php through sql command and loop [php] [sql]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

Basically i have a stockroom ID ($srid) that has 1 or many Categories ($cat).

//Categories have been made in an array[]

Example: Stockroom ID1 has 2 categories. But as user wishes to edit and include another category, this set of codings will allow new values to overwrite old values through comparison - array_diff() :

```
function einv_editStockrm($srid,$code,$name,$desc,$remark,$cat)
{
    $Stockroom = einv_getStockrmDetail($srid);
    $oldCat = $Stockroom["einv_stockrm_cat"];
    $oldCatArr = explode(",",$oldCat);
    $newCatArr = explode(",",$cat);
    $resultCatAdd = array_diff($newCatArr, $oldCatArr);
    $resultCatRemove = array_diff($oldCatArr, $newCatArr);
}
```

My stockroom links to another table called Asset ($Aid).
As stockroom id changes, new data fields are displayed.

**Example:**

Asset 1 has **stockroom ID1** thus consisting of **2 categories**

as mentioned above which leads to **2 data fields(eg:price and date)** to be displayed and to be added, stored in database and able to view in a separate view_asset.php page.

Here comes my problem as user wishes to **edit asset 1**. User changes stockroom to

**stockroom ID2** which consist of a **new data field(eg:warehouse)**.

This will result in previous values **(price and date)** to be wiped out and the view page should only show just this new data field **(warehouse)** result. I'm unable to do so whereby i will still get the old value.

Here are some codes i have in edit asset. 
These is basically my stockroom $cat and checks which one did the user added in:

```
function einv_editAsset
{
if ($stockrmID != $AssetOtherDetail['einv_stockrm_id']) {
        $catCheck = explode(",", $StockrmDetails['einv_stockrm_cat']);
        foreach($catCheck as &$value) {
            if($value == "General Information") {
                $checkGeneral = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Product Information") {
                $checkProduct = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Warranty Information") {
                $checkWarranty = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Sales Parts") {
                $checkSales = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Customer Information") {
                $checkCustomer = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Internal Information") {
                $checkInternal = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Warehouse Information") {
                $checkWarehouse = true;             
            } elseif ($value == "Yearly Reset") {
                $checkYR = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $catCheck = explode(",", $AssetOtherDetail['einv_stockrm_cat']);
        foreach($catCheck as &$value) {
            if($value == "General Information") {
                $checkGeneral = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Product Information") {
                $checkProduct = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Warranty Information") {
                $checkWarranty = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Sales Parts") {
                $checkSales = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Customer Information") {
                $checkCustomer = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Internal Information") {
                $checkInternal = true;
            } elseif ($value == "Warehouse Information") {
                $checkWarehouse = true; 
            } elseif ($value == "Yearly Reset") {
                $checkYR = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit asset sql:

```
//start transaction - Utilizes RollBack in the event of an error somewhere midway thereabouts
    base_executeSQL("START TRANSACTION;");
    $editAssetSQL = "UPDATE einv_asset SET einv_asset_code = '" . $code . "', einv_asset_dlogged = '" . $dlogged . "'
    WHERE einv_asset_code = '" . $oldCode . "' ";
    //Checking and executing the query
    if (!base_executeSQL($editAssetSQL)) {
        $continue = false;
        echo $editAssetSQL;
    }
```

This set of codes will call the relevant data fields as user checks the $cat. Example if user added the general info in stockroom id, it will call the data available in general info.

```
if ($checkGeneral == true) {
        $editGeneralSQL = "UPDATE einv_general_information SET einv_ginfo_status = '" . $status . "',
        einv_ginfo_remark = '" . base_addSlashSQL($remark) . "'
        WHERE einv_ginfo_aid = '" . $oldCode . "' ";
        //Check and execute query
        if(!base_executeSQL($editGeneralSQL)) {
            $continue = false;
            echo $editGeneralSQL;
        }
    } else { $continue = true; }
```

I believe to obtain the edited values, it would require an SQL execution alongside looping my $cat id. 
I dont even know how to begin. Any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($SQL);
while($General_row = base_fetch_array($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL))

if (base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL)!= 0)
{

    // General Information category
    if ($checkGeneral == true) {

        if(einv_checkStockrmCat($General_row['einv_asset_code'],"General"))
        {   
            $addGeneralSQL="INSERT INTO einv_general_information (einv_ginfo_status,einv_ginfo_remark,einv_ginfo_aid)
                VALUES ('" . $status . "','" . base_addSlashSQL($remark) . "','" . $General_row['einv_asset_code'] . "')";

            //Check and execute query
            if(!base_executeSQL($addGeneralSQL)) {
                $continue = false;
                echo $addGeneralSQL;
            }else { $continue = true; }
        }
    } 
}
```

And if the category is false, create another function:

```
function einv_checkStockrmCat
{
    if($category == "General")
    {
        $generalSQL = "SELECT * FROM einv_general_information WHERE einv_ginfo_aid = '" . $assetcode . "') ";
        $get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL = base_executeSQL($generalSQL);
        $total = base_num_rows($get_einv_asset_stockrm_SQL);
        if ($total!= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        elseif($total== 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```